# MainActivity not contain FCM clicable content in intent.extras

Tags: kotlin

This my onMessage in FirebaseMessaging Class

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
        val title = remoteMessage.notification?.title
        val message = remoteMessage.notification?.body
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("remoteMessage", "remote message test")
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        var builder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_health_32dp)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000,1000,1000,100))
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        builder = builder.setContent(getRemoteView(title,message))
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build())
```

And this is my MainActivity that must contain intent extra string, but not contain

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val remoteMessage = intent.extras //this variable not contain intent extras from notification click
}
```

I achieve to ssend data from firebase notification to MainActivity